# The rigth way to navigate through UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have am working on an ebook for the iPad. Every page of the book is a View Controller in the app's StoryBoard, with their page number set as their identifier in Interface Builder. I'm working on the class that implements the navigation, whose role will be to present and dismiss the view controllers. It does so by overlaying a set of buttons on the presented view controller and dealing with their IBActions.

My problem is that some of the viewcontrollers (the even-numbered pages) are never presented! Can anyone see why?

```
@implementation Navigator

UIViewController *currentPageVC;
UIViewController *nextPageVC;

int currentPage = 0;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self getLandingPage];
}

-(void)getLandingPage{

    currentPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Landing"];
    currentPage = 0;
    NSLog(@"Trying to present landing page");
}

-(IBAction)goToNextPage{

    [currentPageVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    currentPage++;    

    nextPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPage ]];
    [self presentModalViewController:nextPageVC animated:YES];

    [nextPageVC.view addSubview:self.view];

    currentPageVC = nextPageVC;

    NSLog(@"Current Page is %d", currentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it. This happened because the call to `presentModalViewController:` happened to soon after `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

In order to fix this, you've to use the new version of it: `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

```
-(IBAction)goToNextPage{    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"dismissed!");
        currentPage++;
        UIViewController *nextPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPage ]];
        [self presentModalViewController:nextPageVC animated:YES];
        [nextPageVC.view addSubview:self.view];

        NSLog(@"Current Page is %d", currentPage);

    }];

}
```